# Let the Stack Overflow Developer Survey participant to uncheck the option if the question is not mandatory

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2021

In the 2021 Stack Overflow Developer Survey, I am unable to uncheck the option in **non-mandatory questions** once I have clicked on them. I can only change the option but not uncheck. Please fix this bug.

If it's not possible to fix this issue, at least provide prefer not to say option in more questions.

According to my opinion, the questions which must have a prefer not to say option are:

1. [image: Which of the following best describes the highest level of formal education that you've completed?]
2. [image: At what age did you write your first line of code or program?]
3. [image: How frequently would you say you visit Stack Overflow?]
4. [image: Do you have a Stack Overflow account?]
5. [image: Do you consider yourself a member of the Stack Overflow community?]
6. [image: Are you a member of any other online developer communities?]
7. [image: What is the primary operating system in which you work?]

Comment: that's how radio buttons work

Comment: @KevinB If the question is not mandatory, the survey participant must have the choice to uncheck.

Comment: I do understand your concern, your request is simply unrealistic

Comment: I'm not sure it will work but have you tried double clicking on them? If that doesn't work, there's not much we can do - we don't control the survey platform - it's likely just how Qualtrics works.

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with your dev tools, but that doesn't necessarily mean the thing you chose will be unchosen depending on how they implemented it

Comment: If they wanted to use radio buttons the correct option would've been to make it mandatory and defaulted to "None of the above" or "Prefer not to say"

Comment: You might want to post this as an answer here: [Take the 2021 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407914/6045800)

Comment: Just finished the survey, and the only radios I ran across without a "No response"/ "Prefer Not to Say" option were on the final page ["how was the survey?"-type questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cePkE.png) (which I wouldn't really count tbh). Did you see others?

Comment: Both of those options *are* responses.

Comment: @Catija I have tried double clicking on them. It doesn't uncheck the option :(

Comment: @Tomerikoo https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407921 Done!

Comment: @zcoop98 I have edited my question. Please check.

Comment: @Random Clearly I was simply unobservant lol, the screenshots are very helpful.

Comment: Looks like there's kinda a secondary option for us - if we can't make the radio unselectable, we could add a "prefer not to say" option - which would, I think, serve a similar purpose?

Comment: @Catija Yeah. I'm OK with this idea.

Comment: @KevinB:  Sure, "Prefer not to say" _is_ and answer, but it's a better option than not being able to unselect an answer, if you change your mind. It's pretty standard UX to allow a user to submit a "blank" vote on non-mandatory radio options...

Comment: @Catija Looks like the issue is fixed.. they've changed from radio buttons to something else. Does this mean [meta-tag:status-completed]?